# Delimiters of program arguments?

Tags: command-line, programming, arguments

What is the syntax to delimit the arguments of a C program.
For example, if I type :

```
./myprogram 1 2 3 | grep result
```

The `| grep result` will be interpreted as arguments (and passed as `argv`). So how to terminate the arguments after `3` ?

Comment: What shell are using? If `|` is not escaped and not between `"` it shouldn't be interpreted as argument...

Comment: I suppose it depends on what shell you use, but most Unix/Linux shell will treat | , ; and & as delimiters between programs/commands, and treat each side as separate program/arguments-combinations.  It's the shell that decide what your program will "see", and it shouldn't pass it the "| grep result" part.  Instead it will take the result (stdout) from your program and pass it to "grep result".

Comment: doesn't it go the reverse way? the result of ./myprogram goes to grep result as an argument?  cat /proc/cpuinfo | less     the output of cat is redirected as an input to less... correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's true. The shell is the one interpreting the command line arguments and passing them to the corresponding commands as it (the shell) is parsing them.

So your C program, when it finally get's executed will only see the arguments 1, 2, and 3. The pipe and everything after is the responsibility of the shell, and will not get passed in as arguments to the C program.

Here's an example, using a bash shell and bash shell script.

#### Example (shell script)

A sample script, `test.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=somefile
[ -f $file ] && rm $file
for var in "$@"
do
  echo "$var" >> $file
done

cat $file
```

Now run the script, results are store in a file, `somefile`:

```
$ ./test.bash 1 2 3 '4 5'
1
2
3
4 5
```

Run it with additional command line arguments:

```
$ ./test.bash 1 2 3 '4 5' | echo hi
hi

$ cat somefile 
1
2
3
4 5
```

In both cases the script, `test.bash` only saw the arguments leading up to the pipe (|). The Bash shell was responsible for parsing the commands, and so it never presented anything after, including the pipe (|).

#### Example (c program)

In case there's any questions about using a shell script, here's a c program that takes the command line arguments and you can see the same behavior with it as well.

The c program is called `testc.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Program name: %s\n", argv[0]);

  while ((argc > 1))
  {
    printf("%s\n",&argv[1][0]);

    ++argv;
    --argc;
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Compile it like so:

```
gcc testc.c -o testc
```

Use it like so:

```
./testc
1
2
3
4 5

$ ./testc 1 2 3 '4 5' | echo hi
hi
```

You can see in the above that only the first 4 arguments are presented to my c program, `testc`.